# Ruby: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 3.1.dev, >= 2.5

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I'm trying to install the [Vagrant plugin](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt) `vagrant-libvirt` on Debian 10. However, Debian 10 does only have Ruby `2.5` and I get the following error message each time I trigger `vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt`:

```
nokogiri requires Ruby version < 3.1.dev, >= 2.5.
```

I've installed all developer dependencies (`apt-get build-dep vagrant ruby-libvir`, `apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev libvirt-dev zlib1g-dev ruby-dev`) as required by the manual, but still get this error. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please upgrade vagrant, because it ships with its own ruby verison.